# While using the skin modifier and the subdivision surface modifier, for some odd reason, a chunk of it is missing

Tags: modeling, modifiers, error

anyone know how to fix this? i've tried for days to no avail, and yes this is related to my last post.

Edit: here's the blender link https://pasteall.org/blend/9eb51ad0504b4d9a8bdbaa513af7379d
[image: all is well, right?]

[image: i wish, but missing chunks of skin just gotta plague me.]

Comment: Hello, could you please highlight the part? Maybe even share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots here's the link https://pasteall.org/blend/9eb51ad0504b4d9a8bdbaa513af7379d

Comment: I don't know the Skin modifier enough but it looks like you can't avoid it: https://blenderartists.org/t/holes-with-skin-modifier/619594/4